# Is there an Android Emulator on OS X?

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

I want to develop an android application without having to purchase an android phone,

1) Is there an android emulator on the mac? the same as on windows?

2) is it better to develop on an android app on a pc, or a mac? same?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) runs on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X, and includes an emulator for development. You can also develop using [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) on Mac OS X if you want, using the ADT plugin.

Whether or not it's "better" is probably a matter of opinion. You have the same tools on all platforms, but drivers and such are a little different on each. However, if you're just using the emulator, then it would probably be about the same on all three. I've found that developing on Linux and Windows is essentially the same, but since I prefer Linux environments, that's what I use.

As side note, if it interests you, the emulator in the SDK is based on [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page).

Comment: +1 Eclipse feels the same on every platform, as do the Android SDK tools. Use the OS that you know.

Comment: It feels awkwardly the same. That is true. Try NetBeans instead: http://blog.screencustoms.com/post/1229245596/a-great-relief-in-developing-android-apps

Comment: These days HAXM, the "Intel® Hardware Accelerated eXecution Manager", is a great and faster alternative to QEMU: http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager. I first learned about HAXM from this post:https://www.addthis.com/blog/2013/07/22/10-tips-for-android-emulator/

Answer (score 5):

Try this one:
Droid.app helps making install android sdk on your osx system.

http://joeworkman.net/blog/post-29568795683